# Need to rearrange and array into dataframe using php

Tags: php, dataframe, matrix

I need to rearrange data into tabular form. e.g. I want to prepare a report that show. Monthly salaries of employees in following form,

| EMPNO | NAME | JAN-21 | FEB-21 | MAR-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jhon | 50000 | 50001 | 50000 |
| 2 | Smith | 60000 | 60001 | 60003 |

Data will be collected from oracle database using

```
oci_parse($con,"select empno, nam, dat, sal from emp_sal where dat between '$firstdate' and 'l$lastdate' ");
```

This will show data into several rows up to down such as

| EMPNO | NAME | MONTH | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | JAN-21 | 50000 |
| 1 | Jhon | MAR-21 | 50000 |
| 2 | Smith | FEB-21 | 60001 |
| 1 | Jhon | FEB-21 | 50001 |
| 2 | Smith | JAN-21 | 60000 |

etc. Hope you do understand my question and will provide me the solution.
I have tried several methods even arrays but cannot find any solution.

I can break query into two, one will get column months and other will be run in a loop to several times to get data. But its too complicated and this will increase server load, from which I am willing to avoid.

This is my first question on this form, hope friends will not disappoint me!

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not group the data by month?

Comment: Please guide me! how to group data using php?

Comment: Why not use `GROUP BY` directly in the query, such that PHP receives the data in grouped form?

Comment: in oracle group by clause will return same data as shown above in second table. It will not generate dynamic columns. Even if we may manage to do so (using Inner/outer joins). PHP will still display data show in second table. But I am willing to display first table shown in question. If you are still sure that what ever is in your mind can solve my problem. Then give me a practical example (for my understanding). Thanks for your reply as well.